# Possible improvements for a a data transformation involving dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

My initial problem is to transform a `List` of `Mapping`s whose values are `List`s of values. The transformed list must contain the cartesian product of all lists (those that are values in the dictionaries) that belong to separate dictionaries (in other words, the values of the lists present in the same directories are "coupled").

Basically, if you disregard the keys of the dictionaries, this would be solved simply with `itertools.product`.

**Input:**

```
[
   {
      ('B3G', 'B1'): [1.0, 2.0], 
      ('B1G', 'B1'): [11.0, 12.0]
   }, 
   {
      ('B2G', 'B1'): [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
   }
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 1.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 2.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 3.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 1.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 2.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 3.5}
]
```

To make the matter more confusing, the keys of each dictionaries are `Tuple`s of strings.

Here is a possible implementation, using a `class` to isolate the whole mess.

```
@dataclass
class ParametricMapping:
"""Abstraction for multi-dimensional parametric mappings."""

mappings: List[Mapping[Tuple[str], Sequence[float]]] = field(default_factory=lambda: [{}])

@property
def combinations(self) -> List[Mapping[Tuple[str], float]]:
    """Cartesian product adapted to work with dictionaries, roughly similar to `itertools.product`."""

    labels = [label for arg in self.mappings for label in tuple(arg.keys())]
    pools = [list(map(tuple, zip(*arg.values()))) for arg in self.mappings]

    def cartesian_product(*args):
        """Cartesian product similar to `itertools.product`"""
        result = [[]]
        for pool in args:
            result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
        return result

    results = []
    for term in cartesian_product(*pools):
        results.append([pp for p in term for pp in p])

    tmp = []
    for r in results:
        tmp.append({k: v for k, v in zip(labels, r)})

    if len(tmp) == 0:
        return [{}]
    else:
        return tmp
```

**Question**: how can I improve this to make it cleaner (priority #1) and faster (#2).

Comment: This sounds like more of a question for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've posted it in Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/211121/52027 .

Comment: This question has now been answered on CodeReview.